# Is this the correct way to create fullscreen webapp?

Tags: css

I have to develop a webapp for smartphone and I need a way to avoid scrolling ( vertical and horizontal ). The webpage has 3 div and I am using these rules:

```
body{ width:100%; height:100%; }
div1{ width:100%; height:40%; }
div2{ width:100%; height:30%; }
div3{ width:100%; height:30%; }
```

So, the sum of all element on the same axis ( x and y ) must be 100%

Is this the correct way to create this kind of webapps ?

Comment: If it results what you desire, it's the correct way.

Comment: To avoid scrolling, you'll have to deal with content that doesn't fit on one page. You can either cut the extra content or make it smaller until it fits. This CSS doesn't do either of those.

Comment: @JJJ the contents are only images. So I could set width and height to 100%. Or not ?

Comment: can you post an image or screen shoot of what you want exactly to clarify your question

Answer (score 1):

This works, as the sum of the `width` and `height` properties of all elements is equal to width and height of the screen, respectively. But, this will distort the shape of the elements. For a better cross-screen app, consider using the CSS `@media` rule to enable the elements to adapt to the shape of the screen. Also make sure to remove the initial margin and padding of the page:

```
// Basic reset
* {
  margin:  0;
  padding: 0;
}
```